# Cannot restart php7.0-fpm

Tags: ubuntu, php, php-fpm

When I run the command `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart` I get nothing. Literally. It just goes to the next line instead of giving me the usual:

```
php7.0-fpm stop/waiting
php7.0-fpm start/running, process 27822
```

Same deal with `start` and `stop` options.

If I do `sudo service --status-all` I see `[ + ]  php7.0-fpm` in the list.

Running `php -v` shows `PHP 7.0.11-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )` so I can confirm it is definitely running.

When I restart PHP service I see this in the `/var/log/php7.0-fpm.log`:

```
[23-Sep-2016 16:32:39] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[23-Sep-2016 16:32:39] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[23-Sep-2016 16:32:39] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 2884
[23-Sep-2016 16:32:39] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[23-Sep-2016 16:32:39] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

No PHP related errors in the syslog.

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

What might be going on here?

Comment: Any relevant log messages ?

Comment: @lain Nope. Not in the console. Not in `/var/log/nginx/default-error.log` referenced in nginx config. Tried restarting the server as well, but no luck.

Comment: OS version / logs?

Comment: @alexus Updated original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu (finally) switched to systemd with 16.04 LTS.

Under systemd, there is no output when you manually start or stop a service, *and the request succeeds*. There is only output when a service fails to start/stop.